# Width height ngx-webcam

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, webrtc

I am using ngx-webcam, and I am setting the frame with a height = 4/3 width and a resolution of {exact: width 480, exact: height: 640}. However, when I run it in practice, the aspect ratio of the frame becomes height = 3/4 width, and it generates the following error message. Does anyone know the reason? Thank you all very much.

I am running it on an Android phone.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfumB.jpg)

```
  <webcam class="webcam-image" style="border-radius: 10px" [width]="this.width*0.85" [height]="this.width*4/3*0.85" [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)" *ngIf="showWebcam"
            [allowCameraSwitch]="allowCameraSwitch" [switchCamera]="nextWebcamObservable"
            [videoOptions]="{ width: {exact: 480}, height: {exact: 640}, facingMode: 'environment'}"
            [imageQuality]="1"
            (cameraSwitched)="cameraWasSwitched($event)"
            (initError)="handleInitError($event)"
    ></webcam>
```